# Problem in Outlook and SharePoint list integration

Tags: email, outlook, discussion-board, integration

I have integrated Outlook with the SharePoint Team Discussion list. It creates a folder inside the Outlook and if I manually drag and drop mail to the folder it works. But when I set rules to move mail from inbox to the SharePoint folder automatically it does not move the mail automatically and shows the following error:

> Task 'SharePoint' reported error (0x00000000) : 'Home - Test Discussion Board - Failed to copy one or more items because some are not compatible with SharePoint. The failed items were moved to your Local Failures folder and replaced with copies from the server. If you need assistance troubleshooting items in your Local Failures folder, a Help topic is available at the following address: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=70300. For details, see the log file.

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue? I will be very grateful.

Comment: I having the same exact issue. Sharepoint calendar (list) on office365 connected to Outlook2013. Once i click through the above error the meeting I set in outlook will sync to Sharepoint.

Answer (score 0):

Rules may not work with SharePoint discussion. When drag and drop emails, there are events triggerred in the background and they do more process in the background.

We are using http://cloud2050.com's solution to collect emails into SharePoint list. It works well with discussions and it can merge emails automtically based on topics.

Comment: Thanks David for your reply.Actually I wanted to do this without using any third party tool.